# Does MySQL not use LIMIT to optimize query select functions?

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, query-optimization

I've got a complex query I have to run in an application that is giving me some performance trouble. I've simplified it here. The database is MySQL 5.6.35 on CentOS.

```
SELECT a.`po_num`, 
       Count(*)          AS item_count, 
       Sum(b.`quantity`) AS total_quantity, 
       Group_concat(`web_sku` SEPARATOR ' ') AS web_skus 
FROM   `order` a 
       INNER JOIN `order_item` b 
               ON a.`order_id` = b.`order_key` 
WHERE  `store` LIKE '%foobar%'
LIMIT  200 offset 0;
```

The key part of this query is where I've placed "foobar" as a placeholder. If this value is something like big_store, the query takes much longer (roughly 0.4 seconds in the query provided here, much longer in the query I'm actually using) than if the value is small_store (roughly 0.1 seconds in the query provided). big_store would return significantly more results if there were not limit.

But there is a limit and that's what surprises me. Both datasets have more than the `LIMIT`, which is only 200. It appears to me that MySQL performing the select functions `COUNT`, `SUM`, `GROUP_CONCAT` for all big_store/small_store rows and then applies the `LIMIT` retroactively. I would imagine that it'd be best to stop when you get to 200.

Could it not do the select functions `COUNT`, `SUM`, `GROUP_CONCAT` actions  *after* grabbing the 200 rows it will use, making my query much much quicker? This seems feasible to me except in cases where there's an `ORDER BY` on one of those rows.

Does MySQL not use `LIMIT` to optimize a query select functions? If not, is there a good reason for that? If so, did I make a mistake in my thinking above?

Comment: You're concerned about query optimization... but you're using `LIKE '%pattern%'`? Kind of penny-wise and pound-foolish.

Comment: My query is greatly simplified here, I wouldn't make too many assumptions about the database architecture based on the query provided.

Comment: I don't like answering "simplified" functions unless the exhibit _exactly_ the same qualities as the original.  Otherwise, the solution for the simplified query _may not_ apply to the big one.

Comment: @RickJames the query provided demonstrates the exact same behavior. I tested and ensured that. I'm only explaining to Bill that the query provided should not be used to make assumptions on the validity of the database design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can stop short due to the `LIMIT`, but that is not a reasonable query since there is no `ORDER BY`.

Without `ORDER BY`, it will pick whatever 200 rows it feels like and stop short.

With an `ORDER BY`, it will have to scan the entire table that contains `store` (*please* qualify columns with which table they come from!).  This is because of the *leading* wildcard.  Only then can it trim to 200 rows.

Another problem -- Without a `GROUP BY`, aggregates (`SUM`, etc) are performed across the entire table (or at least those that remain after filtering).  The `LIMIT` does *not* apply until after that.

Perhaps what you are asking about is MariaDB 5.5.21's "LIMIT_ROWS_EXAMINED".

Think of it this way ... All of the components of a `SELECT` are done in the order specified by the syntax.  Since `LIMIT` is last, it does not apply until after the other stuff is performed.

(There are a couple of exceptions:  (1) `SELECT col...` must be done after `FROM ...`, since it would not know which table(s); (2) The optimizer readily reorders `JOINed` table and clauses in `WHERE ... AND ...`.)

More details on that query.

1. The optimizer peeks ahead, and sees that the `WHERE` is filtering on `order` (that is where `store` is, yes?), so it decides to start with the table `order`.
2. It fetches *all* rows from `order` that match `%foobar%`.
3. For each such row, find the row(s) in `order_item`.  Now it has some number of rows (possibly more than 200) with which to do the aggregates.
4. Perform the aggregates - `COUNT`, `SUM`, `GROUP_CONCAT`.  (Actually this will probably be done as it gathers the rows -- another optimization.)
5. There is now 1 row (with an unpredictable value for a.`po_num`).
6. Skip 0 rows for the `OFFSET` part of the `LIMIT`.  (OK, another out-of-order thingie.)
7. Deliver up to 200 rows.  (There is only 1.)

Add `ORDER BY` (but no `GROUP BY`) -- big deal, sort the 1 row.

Add `GROUP BY` (but no `ORDER BY`) in, now you may have more than 200 rows coming out, and it can stop short.

Add `GROUP BY` *and* `ORDER BY` *and* they are identical, then it *may* have to do a sort for the grouping, but not for the ordering, and it *may* stop at 200.

Add `GROUP BY` *and* `ORDER BY` *and* they are *not* identical, then it *may* have to do a sort for the grouping, and *will* have to re-sort for the ordering, and cannot stop at 200 until *after* the `ORDER BY`.  That is, virtually all the work is performed on all the data.

Oh, and all of this gets worse if you don't have the optimal index.  Oh, did I fail to insist on providing `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?

I apologize for my tone.  I have thrown quite a few tips in your direction; please learn from them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I'm still a little lost to be honest. I don't understand the significance of the leading wildcard, and I also am not familiar with "LIMIT_ROWS_EXAMINED" but will look into it. I'd understand more clearly if you could explain how results might change if the database *did* apply the LIMIT before the selection functions, if that's not asking too much.

Comment: "Leading wildcard" means that an index cannot be used.  It like trying to look up "James" in an alphabetical list, but with only "%ames" -- the ordering of the list is useless.

Comment: A _trailing_ wildcard is a different matter: An index can be used with "Jam%" to quickly find James, Jamestown, Jamison, etc.  Indexes are vital to `SELECT` performance.

Comment: The breakdown makes things very clear. Step number 4 in particular explains a lot. I appreciate you're patience, I've definitely learned a lot from your answer, even beyond the question I initially asked.